# How to post feed on application's facebook wall from an android app?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

In my app user can send posts to their walls but i couldn't manage to find out how to send feeds on application's fan page's wall.

Answer (score 1):

Just change ID of wall to ID of fan page. But you need correct permissions though

Comment: Yeah, this should work the same for pages as it does for users.

Comment: Does user have to like app to post to wall ?